# I am not able to insert the value of selected dropdown menu in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, xampp

Following is select option to retrieve the data from mysql db in php. On selecting the dropdown, I need to insert option value to mysql db.

```
<select device_id='device_id'>;

<?php
require_once('sqlcon.php');

$drop=mysql_query("select * from device");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($drop)){
    echo "<option value='" .$row['device_id']. "'>" . $row['device_id']. "</option>";   
}

?>
</select>
```

I am using the following in add.php . Error is showing only in this line.

```
$device_id=$_POST['device_id'];
```

Comment: There's not much here

Comment: What is the error showing? PARSE SYNTAX ERROR?

Comment: undefined index: device_id in C:\...\ in add.php on line 55

Comment: Make sure the part of the script that processes `$_POST` parameters is inside an `if` that tests whether the form was submitted. Otherwise you'll run it when you're displaying the form the first time, if you use the same script to display and process the form.

Answer (score 2):

Also check that the device_id is set or not.

`isset()` function in PHP determines whether a variable is set and is not NULL. It returns a Boolean value, that is, if the variable is set it will return true and if the variable value is null it will return false.

```
if(isset($_POST['device_id'])){ $device_id = $_POST['device_id']; }
```

Answer (score 2):

your error says it all,your select box does not have a "name" attribute, you need to give it one..

```
<select name='device_id'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
undefined index: device_id in C:\...\ in add.php on line 55
```

It tells what is wrong, $_POST['device_id'] (Index = device_id) is not setted. Make sure you have `<select name='device_id'>...</select>`

```
name='device_id' = $_POST['device_id']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute `onchange="document.forms[0].submit()"` to submit the form on selected option.

Add hidden field in form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit" />
```

Get device_id

```
if(isset($_POST["action"])) {    
    echo $_POST['device_id'];
}
```